# Empty output file while crawling

Tags: python, csv, scrapy, output

I know I already ask a similar question but it is a new spider and I have the same problem ([Crawling data successfully but cannot scraped or write it into csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45431911/crawling-data-successfully-but-cannot-scraped-or-write-it-into-csv))... I put my other spider here with an exemple of the output I should have and all the info I usually need to get an output file... Is there anybody who could help me please? I have to finish this spider on Friday... So, I'm in  hurry!!

The strange thing is that my Fnac.csv is created but always empty... So I tried to run my spider directly on an example of a page I want to crawl and I have all the info I need... So, I don't understand... Maybe the problem comes just from my `Rules` or something?

My spider :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Every import is done for a specific use
import scrapy                                       # Once you downloaded scrapy, you have to import it in your code to use it.
import re                                           # To use the .re() function, which extracts just a part of the text you crawl. It's using regex (regular expressions)
import numbers                                      # To use mathematics things, in this case : numbers.
from fnac.items import FnacItem                     # To return the items you want. Each item has a space allocated in the momery, created in the items.py file, which is in the second cdiscount_test directory.
from urllib.request import urlopen                  # To use urlopen, which allow the spider to find the links in a page that is in the actual page.
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule        # To use rules and LinkExtractor, which allowed the spider to follow every url on the page you crawl.
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor     # Look above.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                       # To crawl an iframe, which is a page in a page in web prgrammation.

# Your spider
class Fnac(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'FnacCom'                             # Name of your spider. You call it in the anaconda prompt.
    allowed_domains = ['fnac.com']               # Web domains allowed by you, your spider cannot enter on a page which is not in that domain.
    start_urls = ['https://www.fnac.com/Index-Vendeurs-MarketPlace/A/']        # The first link you crawl.

    # To allow your spider to follow the urls that are on the actual page.
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_start_url'),
    )

    # Your function that crawl the actual page you're on.
    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        item = FnacItem() # The spider now knowws that the items you want have to be stored in the item variable.

        # First data you want which are on the actual page.
        nb_sales = response.xpath('//body//table[@summary="données détaillée du vendeur"]/tbody/tr/td/span/text()').re(r'([\d]*) ventes')
        country = response.xpath('//body//table[@summary="données détaillée du vendeur"]/tbody/tr/td/text()').re(r'([A-Z].*)')

        # To store the data in their right places.
        item['nb_sales'] = ''.join(nb_sales).strip()
        item['country'] = ''.join(country).strip()

        # Find a specific link on the actual page and launch this function on it. It's the place where you will find your two first data.
        test_list = response.xpath('//a/@href')
        for test_list in response.xpath('.//div[@class="ProductPriceBox-item detail"]'):
            temporary = response.xpath('//div[@class="ProductPriceBox-item detail"]/div/a/@href').extract()
            for i in range(len(temporary)):
                scrapy.Request(temporary[i], callback=self.parse_start_url, meta={'dont_redirect': True, 'item': item})

        # To find the iframe on a page, launch the next function.
        yield scrapy.Request(response.url, callback=self.parse_iframe, meta={'dont_redirect': True, 'item': item})

    # Your function that crawl the iframe on a page
    def parse_iframe(self, response):
        f_item1 = response.meta['item'] # Just to use the same item location you used above.

        # Find all the iframe on a page.
        soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(response.url), "lxml")
        iframexx = soup.find_all('iframe')

        # If there's at least one iframe, launch the next function on it
        if (len(iframexx) != 0):
            for iframe in iframexx:
                yield scrapy.Request(iframe.attrs['src'], callback=self.extract_or_loop, meta={'dont_redirect': True, 'item': f_item1})

        # If there's no iframe, launch the next function on the link of the page where you looked after the potential iframe.
        else:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.url, callback=self.extract_or_loop, meta={'dont_redirect': True, 'item': f_item1})

    # Function to find the other data.
    def extract_or_loop(self, response):
        f_item2 = response.meta['item'] # Just to use the same item location you used above.

        # The rest of the data you want.
        address = response.xpath('//body//div/p/text()').re(r'.*Adresse \: (.*)\n?.*')
        email = response.xpath('//body//div/ul/li[contains(text(),"@")]/text()').extract()
        name = response.xpath('//body//div/p[@class="customer-policy-label"]/text()').re(r'Infos sur la boutique \: ([a-zA-Z0-9]*\s*)')
        phone = response.xpath('//body//div/p/text()').re(r'.*Tél \: ([\d]*)\n?.*')
        siret = response.xpath('//body//div/p/text()').re(r'.*Siret \: ([\d]*)\n?.*')
        vat = response.xpath('//body//div/text()').re(r'.*TVA \: (.*)')

        # If the name of the seller exist, then return the data.
        if (len(name) != 0):
            f_item2['name'] = ''.join(name).strip()
            f_item2['address'] = ''.join(address).strip()
            f_item2['phone'] = ''.join(phone).strip()
            f_item2['email'] = ''.join(email).strip()
            f_item2['vat'] = ''.join(vat).strip()
            f_item2['siret'] = ''.join(siret).strip()
            yield f_item2

        # If not, there was no data on the page and you have to find all the links on your page and launch the first function on them.
        else:
            for sel in response.xpath('//html/body'):
                list_urls = sel.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
                list_iframe = response.xpath('//div[@class="ProductPriceBox-item detail"]/div/a/@href').extract()
                if (len(list_iframe) != 0):
                    for list_iframe in list_urls:
                        yield scrapy.Request(list_iframe, callback=self.parse_start_url, meta={'dont_redirect': True})
                for url in list_urls:
                    yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url), callback=self.parse_start_url, meta={'dont_redirect': True})
```

My settings :

```
BOT_NAME = 'fnac'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['fnac.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'fnac.spiders'
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 2
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'fnac.pipelines.FnacPipeline': 300,
}
```

My pipeline :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

# Define your output file.
class FnacPipeline(CsvItemExporter):
    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        f = open('..\\..\\..\\..\\Fnac.csv', 'w').close()
        file = open('..\\..\\..\\..\\Fnac.csv', 'wb')
        self.files[spider] = file
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        file = self.files.pop(spider)
        file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

My items :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

# Define here the models for your scraped items

# See documentation in:
# http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html

class FnacItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your items :
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    name = scrapy.Field()
    nb_sales = scrapy.Field()
    country = scrapy.Field()
    address = scrapy.Field()
    siret = scrapy.Field()
    vat = scrapy.Field()
    phone = scrapy.Field()
    email = scrapy.Field()
```

The command I write in my prompt to run the spider is :

`scrapy crawl FnacCom`

An example of output is :

```
2017-08-08 10:21:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/TV-Panasonic/TV-par-marque/nsh474980/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:21:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/TV-Philips/TV-par-marque/nsh474981/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:21:58 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/TV-Sony/TV-par-marque/nsh475001/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:01 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/TV-LG/TV-par-marque/nsh474979/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:03 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/TV-Samsung/TV-par-marque/nsh474984/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:06 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/TV-Television/TV-par-marque/shi474972/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:08 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/TV-Television/TV-par-prix/shi474946/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:11 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/TV-Television/TV-par-taille-d-ecran/shi474945/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:12 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/TV-Television/TV-par-Technologie/shi474944/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:15 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/Smart-TV-TV-connectee/TV-par-Technologie/nsh474953/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/TV-QLED/TV-par-Technologie/nsh474948/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/TV-4K-UHD/TV-par-Technologie/nsh474947/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/Toutes-les-TV/TV-Television/nsh474940/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:26 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 459 pages (at 24 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-08-08 10:22:26 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/TV-Television/shi474914/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:28 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/partner/canalplus#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:34 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/Meilleures-ventes-TV/TV-Television/nsh474942/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:37 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/Toutes-nos-Offres/Offres-de-remboursement/shi159784/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:38 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/Offres-Adherents/Toutes-nos-Offres/nsh81745/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:41 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/labofnac#bl=MMtvh#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:44 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/Lecteur-et-Enregistreur-DVD-Blu-Ray/Lecteur-DVD-Blu-Ray/shi475063/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/TV-OLED/TV-par-Technologie/nsh474949/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/Lecteur-DVD-Portable/Lecteur-et-Enregistreur-DVD-Blu-Ray/nsh475064/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/Home-Cinema/Home-Cinema-par-marque/shi475116/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/Univers-TV/Univers-Ecran-plat/cl179/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
2017-08-08 10:22:55 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.fnac.com/Casque-TV-HiFi/Casque-par-usage/nsh450507/w-4#bl=MMtvh> (referer: https://www.fnac.com)
```

Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: Your spider has a lot of problems. I'd recommend dropping Crawlspider and using standard Spider class as you are misusing CrawlSpider here.

Comment: Ok, thank you!! I'll begin by doing that... What are the other problems please?

Comment: If I want to use the `LinkExtractor()`, I have to write `CrawlSpider` instead of `scrapy.Spider` isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but here you are trying to crawl _every_ link on the website with empty linkextractor. What's the goal of your spider? To crawl products displayed on the website?

Comment: My goal is to find every seller on the website. So, I try to crawl every link until I have reached all the seller's page. I don't know what to put on `linkextractor()` then, could you guide me on this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small code refactor to show off how the spider could be written explicitly without using crawlspider and using common scrapy idioms:

```
class Fnac(Spider):
    name = 'fnac.com' 
    allowed_domains = ['fnac.com'] 
    start_urls = ['https://www.fnac.com/Index-Vendeurs-MarketPlace/0/']  # The first link you crawl.

    def parse(self, response):
        # parse sellers
        sellers = response.xpath("//h1[contains(selftext(),'MarketPlace')]/following-sibling::ul/li/a/@href").extract()
        for url in sellers:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_seller)

        # parse other pages A-Z
        pages = response.css('.pagerletter a::attr(href)').extract()
        for url in pages:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_seller(self, response):
        nb_sales = response.xpath('//body//table[@summary="données détaillée du vendeur"]/tbody/tr/td/span/text()').re(r'([\d]*) ventes')
        country = response.xpath('//body//table[@summary="données détaillée du vendeur"]/tbody/tr/td/text()').re(r'([A-Z].*)')
        item = FnacItem()
        # To store the data in their right places.
        item['nb_sales'] = ''.join(nb_sales).strip()
        item['country'] = ''.join(country).strip()
        # go to details page now
        details_url = response.xpath("//iframe/@src[contains(.,'retour')]").extract_first()
        yield Request(details_url, self.parse_seller_details,
                      meta={'item': item})  # carry over our item to next response

    def parse_seller_details(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']  # get item that's got filled in `parse_seller`
        address = response.xpath('//body//div/p/text()').re(r'.*Adresse \: (.*)\n?.*')
        email = response.xpath('//body//div/ul/li[contains(text(),"@")]/text()').extract()
        # parse here
        yield item
```

Comment: Ok, I just met a genius who did my spider in five minutes... Thank you so much!!
Could you explain to me the difference between `response.css` and `response.xpath` please? Because you use both of them

Comment: And do you know how to crawl the links that are redirected? I mean, once they are redirected to the correct page, is it possible to crawl that correct page?

Comment: @P.Postrique `.css` uses css selectors and `.xpath` is using xpath selectors :D Both of them are great and valid ways to parse the html page. Generally css selectors are less powerful but tend to be short adn simple to write, while xpath selectors are a bit more on the complex side but are significantly more powerful allowing all kinds of crazy tricks. Regarding redirect: scrapy handles redirects automatically via redirect middleware so you needn't worry about that.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your useful help!! I don't know if we can put some marks on people on this website, but if it's possible, I'll put you a good one for sure!!

Comment: A last question and after I let you... Do you know why scrapy mix the item I ask in `parse_seller` function? I just add my `nb_sales` and `country` in that function because it's on this page but scrapy put the same `nb_sales` and `country` for many sellers...

Comment: @P.Postrique your original code was close to doing this. The issue is that you should create new Item for each _seller_ where you create an item for each seller _page_ in your original code. See my edit for the implementation.